# How to set today as default date in angular bootstrap date picker when component loading?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

In my component, I have a bootstrap date picker that allows users to pick a date like this.

[image]

What I want is to display today`s date by default when a user comes to this page.

So far

```
<form>
       <div class="form-inline">
            <label for="date">Select a date</label>
                <input
                  name="date"
                  type="date"
                  id="datepicker"
                  class="form-control mt-1 mb-2 ml-3"
                  [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
                  [(ngModel)]="selectedDateValue"
                  #vdate="ngModel"
                  (ngModelChange)="searchPayments('selectedDateValue', $event)"
                />
         </div>
 </form>
```

so in my ts file

```
 searchPayments(type, keyword){
    this.selectedDate = keyword;
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

set `selectedDateValue = new Date();` in your component.ts file and it will date will be set in datepicker.